# SoapUI empty response

Tags: web-services, symfony, soap, soapui

I've developed a symfony2 SOAP webservice. It's not the full-blown symfony2 installation, we cherry-picked the apps we like - or, more truthful, the ones that actually worked with the code-base.

- I followed the steps to create a [symfony SOAP webservice](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/web_services/php_soap_extension.html).
- I created a testfile which I execute from the CLI.
- Since it's all PHP I'm using the internal SOAPServer/SOAPClient-classes

I got this working just fine. I also managed to lock down the application with basic authentication. Enough of background.

I installed SoapUI for additional testing. The publicly exposed methods shows up just fine. The "HelloWorld" doesn't require any input but still, the response is always empty. Nothing of value in the soapui log. HTTP code response 200.

I *think* the endpoint is correct, it hasn't slipped to https or a different port.

I'm confused. Why is it working when running the php-client but not the soapUI?

**Edit:**

I'm using the Symfony..Response-class for returning data. When I change the headers (Response::headers::set) they are passed onto soapUI.

**Edit 2:**

If I var_dump the Symfony response-object the content is empty (length 0). Still, as mentioned above, the soapClient returns the response as a valid soap message.

When circumventing symfony's response object (and routing controllers) soapUI gets a correct response.

WHAT is going on?

Comment: Have you looked at the raw log? What does that show? What are you expecting to see?

Comment: The raw response? It shows the headers:
`HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Thu, 16 Oct 2014 10:10:40 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.4-14+deb7u14
Cache-Control: no-cache
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8`
I'm expecting a string "Hello world!"

Comment: It was coming back to a symfony routing problem. Quite obvious once realized, but the amount of parameters to tweak generating obscure and non-sense errors is vast.

Comment: Good stuff...may i suggest that you put your solution as an answer so that others may not have to struggle as much as you did.

Comment: I'll do that (even though it's not appropiate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was found in several steps.

First the routing file was setup as this

```
THE_Service:
  path: /THE/{service}
  defaults: { _controller: '..path/to/controller:method' }
```

...and no routing for /THE - which is the actual path being processed.

And (this is not properly solved yet) for some reason the endpoint from the (dynamically created) wsdl-file was with an extra slash at the end, and the rewrite-rule in the .htaccess caused a 301, thus dropping the POST-data. (I don't know if this is the way it's supposed to be).